# Python update dictionary based on key value pair

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

this question is how to check two dictionary list and for same keys and update main dictionary with key value pair from other dictionary.

## First dictionary

```
main = [
{'country': u'CYPRUS', 'naziv': 'AKEL', 'FCI': 2}, 
{'country': u'CYPRUS', 'naziv': 'DIKO', 'FCI': 4}, 
]
```

## Second

```
second = [
{'likes': '8625.00', 'talks': '1215.00', 'naziv': 'AKEL'}, 
{'likes': '2746.00', 'talks': 0, 'naziv': 'DIKO'}, 
]
```

## Final output - example

```
output = [
    {'country': u'CYPRUS', 'naziv': 'AKEL', 'FCI': 2,'likes': '8625.00', 'talks': '1215.00'}
    {'country': u'CYPRUS', 'naziv': 'DIKO', 'FCI': 4,'likes': '2746.00', 'talks': 0}, 
]
```

Is there any fast way to do this. I was trying with update one dictionary but dont works.

```
for dt, k in itertools.groupby(sorted(second, key=itemgetter('naziv')), key=itemgetter('naziv')):
    maindict = {'naziv': dt}
    for d in k:
        maindict.update(d)
    main.append(maindict)
```

Python 2.7

Comment: Isn't it that fast for you?...

Comment: This is fair for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one may be -

```
import itertools
main = [
{'country': u'CYPRUS', 'naziv': 'AKEL', 'FCI': 2}, 
{'country': u'CYPRUS', 'naziv': 'DIKO', 'FCI': 4}, 
]
second = [
{'likes': '8625.00', 'talks': '1215.00', 'naziv': 'AKEL'}, 
{'likes': '2746.00', 'talks': 0, 'naziv': 'DIKO'}, 
]


lst = sorted(itertools.chain(main,second), key=lambda x:x['naziv'])
list_c = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x:x['naziv']):
    d = {}
    for dct in v:
        d.update(dct)
    list_c.append(d)
print list_c
```

"Shemeless copy of mgilson"

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just update the `main` dictionary list with same `key` values from `second` dictionary, simply this way:

```
>>> for i,d in enumerate(second):
    main[i].update(second[i])


>>> main
[{'likes': '8625.00', 'FCI': 2, 'talks': '1215.00', 'country': u'CYPRUS', 'naziv': 'AKEL'}, {'likes': '2746.00', 'FCI': 4, 'talks': 0, 'country': u'CYPRUS', 'naziv': 'DIKO'}]
```