# Concatenate Two List of Dictionaries on Key/Value Pair in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries. How do I concatenate them based on a key/value that is common in both?

data_list:

```
[{'app': u'568',
  'browser_version': u'0',
  'cost': u'9.4547e-08',
  'device': u'iPad',
  'device_brand': u'Apple',
  'device_family': u'iPad',
  'device_os': u'iOS',
  'device_os_version': u'11.3',
  'end_time': u'2018-05-03',
  'key': '1',
  'latency': 0.435227,
  'megacycles': 370.0,
  'ua_parse': u'40.10.7'},
 {'app': u'571',
  'browser_version': u'66.0.3359',
  'cost': u'1.3075e-08',
  'device': u'0',
  'device_brand': u'0',
  'device_family': u'Other',
  'device_os': u'Mac OS X',
  'device_os_version': u'10.12.6',
  'end_time': u'2018-05-07',
  'key': '2',
  'latency': 0.191712,
  'megacycles': 146.0,
  'ua_parse': u'5.0'}]
```

and ret_data_list:

```
[{u'key': [u'1'], u'predictions': [0.044329315423965454]},
 {u'key': [u'2'], u'predictions': [-0.17194432020187378]}]
```

I would like to concatenate on `'key'`. I have tried this code from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784050/python-update-dictionary-based-on-key-value-pair)

```
lst = sorted(itertools.chain(data_list,ret_data_list), key=lambda x:x['key'])
list_c = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x:x['key']):
    d = {}
    for dct in v:
        d.update(dct)
    list_c.append(d)
print list_c
```

Which printed a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{u'predictions': [0.044329315423965454], u'key': [u'1']},
 {u'predictions': [-0.17194432020187378], u'key': [u'2']},
 {'megacycles': 370.0,
  'latency': 0.435227,
  'app': u'568',
  'device_os_version': u'11.3',
  'ua_parse': u'40.10.7',
  'device_family': u'iPad',
  'browser_version': u'0',
  'cost': u'9.4547e-08',
  'device_brand': u'Apple',
  'end_time': u'2018-05-03',
  'key': '1',
  'device': u'iPad',
  'device_os': u'iOS'},
 {'megacycles': 146.0,
  'latency': 0.191712,
  'app': u'571',
  'device_os_version': u'10.12.6',
  'ua_parse': u'5.0',
  'device_family': u'Other',
  'browser_version': u'66.0.3359',
  'cost': u'1.3075e-08',
  'device_brand': u'0',
  'end_time': u'2018-05-07',
  'key': '2',
  'device': u'0',
  'device_os': u'Mac OS X'}]
```

What I would like to have is a list that looks like this where predictions are appended to data_list matched by `key` (so where `'key':'1' == u'key': [u'1']`)

```
[{'app': u'568',
      'browser_version': u'0',
      'cost': u'9.4547e-08',
      'device': u'iPad',
      'device_brand': u'Apple',
      'device_family': u'iPad',
      'device_os': u'iOS',
      'device_os_version': u'11.3',
      'end_time': u'2018-05-03',
      'key': '1',
      'latency': 0.435227,
      'megacycles': 370.0,
      'ua_parse': u'40.10.7',
      'predictions': 0.044329315423965454},
     {'app': u'571',
      'browser_version': u'66.0.3359',
      'cost': u'1.3075e-08',
      'device': u'0',
      'device_brand': u'0',
      'device_family': u'Other',
      'device_os': u'Mac OS X',
      'device_os_version': u'10.12.6',
      'end_time': u'2018-05-07',
      'key': '2',
      'latency': 0.191712,
      'megacycles': 146.0,
      'ua_parse': u'5.0',
      'predictions': -0.17194432020187378}]
```

Comment: `[u'1']` is not comparable to `'1'` (list vs string).

Comment: can you post what is the desired outcome look like?

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan I have updated the question with my desired outcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I looked at the code,two dicts **"data_list"** and **"ret_data_list"** have 'key' in their dict but the values are different. The "ret_data_list" contains 'key' but has a list as it's value **( u'key' : [u'1'] )**. You need to change the type of that value in "ret_data_list" and make it **( u'key': '1' )**.
>
> After you make the values for "key" same in both the dicts the code fragment runs properly.
>
> You can try the this code to change the "key" value in "ret_data_list":-

```
for data in ret_data_list:
   data['key'] = (''.join(data['key']).encode("ascii","ignore"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have lists `lst1` and `lst2`, you can iterate then in a nested `for` loop. This is inefficient, but it is in the nature of manipulating list of dictionaries.

The only additional complication is that you need to extract the only element of your list values in `lst2` dictionaries.

```
for item1 in lst1:
    for item2 in lst2:
        if item1['key'] == item2[u'key'][0]:
            item1['predictions'] = item2[u'predictions'][0]
```

Comment: Would I just insert this `for` loop into my existing function?

Comment: Yes, and remember to return your lists.